# Problem with adding multiple images to the elements (javascript loop Issue)

Tags: javascript

I would like to add multiple photos from the Array in this code to the elements, but it adds just one photo from the Array to the first Element.
I tried adding for loop, but I dont know where to start and where to end the loop. Could you please take a look to the code using the link (codepen)?
thank you

```
let zoomLevel = 1;

const images = [
    {
        thumb: 'http://localhost:8080/links/works/Print/001.webp',
        hires: 'http://localhost:8080/links/works/Print/001.webp'
    },
    {
        thumb: 'https://tasvir-graphic.de/links/works/digital/unterwelt.webp',
        hires: 'https://tasvir-graphic.de/links/works/digital/unterwelt.webp'
    }
]

// set to random image
let img = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

image.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].setAttribute('href', img.hires);
image.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('src', img.thumb);

const preloadImage = url => {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
}

preloadImage(img.hires);

const enterImage = function(e) {
    zoom.classList.add('show', 'loading');
    clearTimeout(clearSrc);
    
    let posX, posY, touch = false;
    
    if (e.touches) {
        posX = e.touches[0].clientX;
        posY = e.touches[0].clientY;
        touch = true;
    } else {
        posX = e.clientX;
        posY = e.clientY;
    }
```

You can check this better using Codepen **[HERE.](https://codepen.io/Tasvir2/pen/mdEVGeM)**

Comment: If you simplify the question to the essence of the problem you might get a better answer sooner.

Comment: @BenAston this code adds one image from the array to the first element of the class, how to add all images from the array to the all elemnts of html? what do't you understand?

Comment: do u mean that i need to reduce the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Reporter, but I've allready done this editing my code for two days. :)

```
const zoo = document.querySelectorAll('.zoom');
const zooImg = document.querySelectorAll('.zoom-image');
const pic = document.querySelectorAll(".image");

let clearSrc;
let zoomLevel = 1;

const digiImgs = [{
    thumb: 'https://tasvir-graphic.de/links/works/digital/MuZe.webp',
    hires: 'https://tasvir-graphic.de/links/works/digital/MuZe.webp'
  },
  {
    thumb: 'https://tasvir-graphic.de/links/works/digital/unterwelt.webp',
    hires: 'https://tasvir-graphic.de/links/works/digital/unterwelt.webp'
  },
  {
    thumb: 'https://tasvir-graphic.de/links/works/digital/takeCare.webp',
    hires: 'https://tasvir-graphic.de/links/works/digital/takeCare.webp'
  },
]

// set to random image
for (var i = 0; i < pic.length; i++) {

  let img = digiImgs[i];
  pic[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].setAttribute('href', img.hires);
  pic[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('src', img.thumb);

  const preloadImage = url => {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
  }
  preloadImage(img.hires);

  const enterImage = function (e) {
    var zoo = this.parentNode.childNodes[3];
    zoo.classList.add('show', 'loading');
    clearTimeout(clearSrc);

    let posX, posY, touch = false;

    if (e.touches) {
      posX = e.touches[0].clientX;
      posY = e.touches[0].clientY;
      touch = true;
    } else {
      posX = e.clientX;
      posY = e.clientY;
    }

    touch
      ?
      zoo.style.top = `${posY - zoo.offsetHeight / 1.25}px` :
      zoo.style.top = `${posY - zoo.offsetHeight / 2}px`;
      zoo.style.left = `${posX - zoo.offsetWidth / 2}px`;

    let originalImage = this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href');
    var zoImg = this.parentNode.childNodes[3].childNodes[1];
    zoImg.setAttribute('src', originalImage);

    // remove the loading class
    zoImg.onload = function () {
      setTimeout(() => {
        zoo.classList.remove('loading');
      }, 500);
    }

  }


  const leaveImage = function () {
    // remove scaling to prevent non-transition 
    var zoImg = this.parentNode.childNodes[3].childNodes[1];
    var zoo = this.parentNode.childNodes[3];
    zoo.style.transform = null;
    zoomLevel = 1;
    zoo.classList.remove('show');
    clearSrc = setTimeout(() => {
      zoImg.setAttribute('src', '');
    }, 250);
  }

  const move = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var zoImg = this.parentNode.childNodes[3].childNodes[1];
    var zoo = this.parentNode.childNodes[3];

    let posX, posY, touch = false;

    if (e.touches) {
      posX = e.touches[0].clientX;
      posY = e.touches[0].clientY;
      touch = true;
    } else {
      posX = e.clientX;
      posY = e.clientY;
    }

    // move the zoom a little bit up on mobile (because of your fat fingers :<)
    touch ?
      zoo.style.top = `${posY - zoo.offsetHeight / 1.25}px` :
      zoo.style.top = `${posY - zoo.offsetHeight / 2}px`;
      zoo.style.left = `${posX - zoo.offsetWidth / 2}px`;

    let percX = (posX - this.offsetLeft) / this.offsetWidth,
        percY = (posY - this.offsetTop) / this.offsetHeight;

    let zoomLeft = -percX * zoImg.offsetWidth + (zoo.offsetWidth / 2),
        zoomTop = -percY * zoImg.offsetHeight + (zoo.offsetHeight / 2);

    zoImg.style.left = `${zoomLeft}px`;
    zoImg.style.top = `${zoomTop}px`;
  }


  pic[i].addEventListener('mouseover', enterImage);
  pic[i].addEventListener('touchstart', enterImage);

  pic[i].addEventListener('mouseout', leaveImage);
  pic[i].addEventListener('touchend', leaveImage);

  pic[i].addEventListener('mousemove', move);
  pic[i].addEventListener('touchmove', move);


  pic[i].addEventListener('wheel', e => {

    var zoo = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[3];
    console.log(zoo);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.deltaY > 0 ? zoomLevel-- : zoomLevel++;

    if (zoomLevel < 1) zoomLevel = 1;
    if (zoomLevel > 3) zoomLevel = 3;

    console.log(`zoom level: ${zoomLevel}`);
    zoo.style.transform = `scale(${zoomLevel})`;
  });
}
```

but there is a problem with the touch. When I touch using mobile, the photo works like a link and opens the photo. How to use preventDefault Touch?

Comment: First: This is actually not an answer, this is another question.
Second: Try  `return false;` by adding it at the end of href attribute, so the link should not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
    const image = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
    /* Store the number of all elements with css class 'image' */
    let imageElementsCount = image.length;

    for (index = 0; index < imageElementsCount; index++)
    {
        let arrayElementPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

        /* Receive the requested element from array with image objects */
        let imageObject = images[arrayElementPos];

        preloadImage(imageObject.hires);

        /* Assign received image properties to your html element */
        image[index].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].setAttribute('href', imageObject.hires);
        image[index].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('src', imageObject.thumb);

        image[index].addEventListener('mouseover', enterImage);
        image[index].addEventListener('touchstart', enterImage);

        image[index].addEventListener('mouseout', leaveImage);
        image[index].addEventListener('touchend', leaveImage);

        image[index].addEventListener('mousemove', move);
        image[index].addEventListener('touchmove', move);

        image[index].addEventListener('wheel', e =>
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.deltaY > 0 ? zoomLevel-- : zoomLevel++;

            if (zoomLevel < 1) zoomLevel = 1;
            if (zoomLevel > 5) zoomLevel = 5;

            console.log(`zoom level: ${zoomLevel}`);
            zoom.style.transform = `scale(${zoomLevel})`;
        });
    }
```

The loop is working until all founded divs got an assignment.

ToDos:

Remove in line

```
const image = document.querySelectorAll('.image')[0];
```

the [0].

Next step: Take a look into the body of for loop. Remove your lines of code in your original code

Comment: Thank you, normaly the events work with the first image, but as soon as i add loop to add the  images, images will be added, but the events wont work any more. I mean mouseover, zoom... event.

Comment: as you can see in my code using codepen, there are two blank elements, could you pleae make them work?

Comment: This is the original code: https://codepen.io/creme/pen/gOYrvxM All I want is to add more photos on the page.

Comment: @hamid I found a mistake in my code and I added the assignments for the event listernes. According code pen it works.

Comment: Could you check the code in my answer why when I tauch the photo, it opens the picture instead of zooming? I mean how can I preventDefault() the tauch function?